# Complex queries using Rails query language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have a query used for statistical purposes. It breaks down the number of users that have logged-in a given number of times. User has_many installations and installation has a login_count.

```
select total_login as 'logins', count(*) as `users` 
  from (select u.user_id, sum(login_count) as total_login 
          from user u 
               inner join installation i on u.user_id = i.user_id
               group by u.user_id) g
  group by total_login;

+--------+-------+
| logins | users |
+--------+-------+
| 2      |     3 |
| 6      |     7 |
| 10     |     2 |
| 19     |     1 |
+--------+-------+
```

Is there some elegant ActiveRecord style `find` to obtain this same information? Ideally as a hash collection of logins and users: `{ 2=>3, 6=>7, ...`

I know I can use sql directly but wanted to know how this could be solved in rails 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# Our relation variables(RelVars)
U =Table(:user, :as => 'U')
I =Table(:installation, :as => 'I')

# perform operations on relations
G =U.join(I)  #(implicit) will reference final joined relationship

#(explicit) predicate = Arel::Predicates::Equality.new U[:user_id], I[:user_id]
G =U.join(I).on( U[:user_id].eq(I[:user_id] ) 

# Keep in mind you MUST PROJECT for this to make sense
G.project(U[:user_id], I[:login_count].sum.as('total_login'))

# Now you can group
G=G.group(U[:user_id])

#from this group you can project and group again (or group and project)
# for the final relation
TL=G.project(G[:total_login].as('logins') G[:id].count.as('users')).group(G[:total_login])
```

Keep in mind this is VERY verbose because I wanted to show you the order of operations not just the "Here is the code". The code can actually be written with half the code.

The hairy part is Count(*)
As a rule, any attribute in the SELECT that is not used in an aggregate should appear in the GROUP BY so be careful with count(*)

Why would you group by the total_login count?
At the end of the day I would simply ask why don't you just do a count of the total logins of all installations since the user information is made irrelevant by the outer most count grouping.

Comment: Thank you. The real question was how could something like this be done. Ultimatly, I'm just trying to get a handle on some of the more interesting cases beyond find someone by name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find anything as efficient as having the db do the work. Remember that you don't want to have to retrieve the rows from the db, you want the db itself to compute the answer by grouping the data.

If you want to push the SQL further into the database, you can create the query as a view in the database and then use a Rails ActiveRecord class to retrieve the results.

Comment: I've just learnt something here on the AR mapping to a db view. Useful to know, thanks :)

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'll look into it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

In the end imo the SQL syntax is way more readable. This arel stuff is just slowing me down all the time when I only need just a tiny bit more complexity. It's just another syntax you have learn, not worth it imo. I'd stick to SQL in these cases.

Comment: just because there is a long learning curve it doesn't mean that it is not worth learning. Since arel is out, I've never written SQL anymore and I am very happy about it.